# Why does "msg.sendToTarget" stop the loop?

Tags: java, android, handler

Handler hnd = new Handler() {

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        int id = sequence.get(msg.arg1);

        if(msg.arg1 % 2 == 0) {
            sq.get(id-1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);
        } else {
            sq.get(id-1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i <= sequence.size()-1; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    Message msg = hnd.obtainMessage();
                    msg.arg1 = i;
                    msg.setTarget(hnd); // EDITED
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                    record_tv.setText(""+i);
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {

            }
        }
    });

    background.start();
}
```

the code arrives to msg.sendToTarget(), does its things and then never came back

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't catch exceptions and then ignore them. If you at least logged the exception you might be able to answer your own question.

Comment: probably record_tv.setTexT() causes the block catch to be called, and the run goes to its end. Probaby you want to inver the for and the try/catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendToTarget();`  throws a null pointer exception it you have no set a receiver with `setTarget(Handler)`.

Also, in your code I see

```
record_tv.setText(""+i);
```

this line, inside your thread will throw a

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException
```

Comment: thank you, you solved my problem, but now i don't know why, it just reaches the sq.get(id-1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show); the 1st time, and the 3rd (and the 2nd it does nothing), but it never reaches the sq.get(id-1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);

Comment: probably record_tv.setTexT() causes the block catch to be called, and the run goes to its end. Probaby you want to invert the for and the try/catch?

Comment: it doesnt change anything @blackbelt, it works fine now, the only problem is that it should set the image to square_show, wait 2 secs, square and then change ImageView and do the same

Comment: fill free to ask a new question if you are not able to fix. I am glad it worked